# Can I get Mathematica to recognize common series expansions of trigonometric functions?

Tags: pattern-matching, series-expansion, trigonometry, approximation

I have some complicated functions from numerical procedures that go to simple trig functions in the limit of small time-steps. For example, I can calculate that one of these functions goes to:

```
x - 2x^3 / 3 + 2x^5 / 15
```

This is $\sin{x} \cos{x}$ minus terms of $O(x^7)$ and higher. Is there any way for *Mathematica* to recognize such a pattern automatically? I have other similar series expansions and I don't want to have to find all of them manually.

---Edit---

Thank you Szabolcs and corey979! You asked for more examples/background so here it is. I wanted to convert a 2x2 matrix of polynomials to trigonomic functions. I can obtain this matrix to arbitrary order in some small parameter h. To first order that looks like:

> `{{1 + h (t - (2 t^3)/3 + (2 t^5)/15), h (t^2 - t^4/3 + (2 t^6)/45)}, {h (t^2 - t^4/3 + (2 t^6)/45), 1 + h (-t + (2 t^3)/3 - (2 t^5)/15)}}`

To second order that looks like:

> `{{1 + h^2 (t^2/2 - t^4/6) + h (t - (2 t^3)/3 + (2 t^5)/15), h (t^2 - t^4/3 + (2 t^6)/45)}, {h (t^2 - t^4/3 + (2 t^6)/45), 1 + h^2 (t^2/2 - t^4/6) + h (-t + (2 t^3)/3 - (2 t^5)/15)}}`

etc

For a single matrix element, I was able to collect the coefficients of various orders of h and use With the data and FindFunction approach to turn those coefficents into trigonomic functions. It seems to work okay if I have the coefficients have enough terms, but I can get pretty wacky numbers if it doesn't have enough terms. I use this code:

```
findtrigfunc[inseries_] :=  Module[{outseries=inseries},
outseries = outseries //CoefficientList[#,h]&;
For[i=1, i <= Length[outseries],i++, 
{data = Table[Evaluate@{x, outseries[[i]] //. t->x}, {x, 0, 1, 0.01}];
outseries[[i]] = FindFormula[data, x, TargetFunctions -> {Times,Sin, Cos}]}];
Sum[outseries[[i]]*h^(i- 1) , {i,1,Length[outseries]}]//.x->t]
```

Here's what that produces for the first matrix element up to second order in h and order 7 in t:

> `1. + 1.0043 h Cos[t] Sin[t] + h^2 (-0.00618535 + 0.596221 Sin[Sin[t]]^2)`

When I increase the order in t from 7 to 11, I get extra terms that get me a more reasonable answer:

> `1. + h^2 (0.49996 - 0.499954 Cos[t]^2) + 1.00001 h Cos[t] Sin[t]`

Comment: If the expressions appear exactly as written, you should be able to use `ReplaceAll` (i.e. `/.` replacement rules); it seems difficult to do in more general cases, though.

Comment: Can you provide a few more examples of such series, and what functions do they come from?

Answer (score 6):

If you have sufficiently many terms, `FindGeneratingFunction` may be able to do exactly this. But I wasn't having much luck with it, so I went in a roundabout way:

This is the expression. The more terms you have the better it works.

```
expr = Normal@Series[Sin[x] Cos[x], {x, 0, 8}]
(* x - (2 x^3)/3 + (2 x^5)/15 - (4 x^7)/315 *)
```

Extract coefficients:

```
coeff = CoefficientList[expr, x]
(* {0, 1, 0, -(2/3), 0, 2/15, 0, -(4/315)} *)
```

Try `FindGeneratingFunction`. It doesn't work here.  But if we had computed the series to order 12, it *would* work, and it would return `1/2 Sin[2 x]` (try it).

```
FindGeneratingFunction[coeff, x]
(* FindGeneratingFunction[{0, 1, 0, -(2/3), 0, 2/15, 
  0, -(4/315)}, x] *)
```

Construct sequence and get rid of the factorials, in the hope that it leads to simpler terms:

```
seq = {#1, #1! #2} & @@@ Transpose@{Range[0, Length[coeff] - 1], coeff}
(* {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 0}, {3, -4}, {4, 0}, {5, 16}, {6, 0}, {7, -64}} *)
```

Now try `FindSequenceFunction`. When this method fails, this is where it will fail.

```
fun = FindSequenceFunction[seq]
(* -2^(-2 + #1) ((-I)^(1 + #1) + I^(1 + #1)) & *)
```

Re-sum the result:

```
Sum[fun[k]/k! x^k, {k, 0, Infinity}]
(* -(1/4) I E^(-2 I x) (-1 + E^(4 I x)) *)
```

Simplify:

```
FullSimplify[%]
(* Cos[x] Sin[x] *)
```

Comment: If you consider that the length of the pattern in the series of `Sin[]` and `Cos[]` is `4`, a series of order `8` is barely long enough to guess there is a pattern (at least naively).

Comment: @MichaelE2 I did edit the post to note that it works with 12 (a few minutes ago).

Comment: @MichaelE2 Do you know how FindGeneratingFunction works, or how such a thing may be implemented?

Comment: No, I do not for sure, but I'd bet a small amount of money the magic word is "holonomic." For an overview, see [Kauers, The Holonomic Toolkit](http://www.algebra.uni-linz.ac.at/people/mkauers/publications/kauers13.pdf), which I've only skimmed.  Sect. 4 describes "guessing" for this sort of problem.

Answer (score 5):

A similar idea to Szabolcs, but I was waiting for a few more examples from the OP. Here goes.

```
f[x_] := x - 2 x^3/3 + 2 x^5/15
```

Create some data from it

```
data = Table[Evaluate@{x, Normal@f[x]}, {x, 0, 0.1, 0.01}];
```

and try to `FindFormula`:

```
FindFormula[data, x, TargetFunctions -> {Times, Sin, Cos}]
```

> Cos[x] Sin[x]

---

A few made-up examples:

```
g[x_] := Normal@Series[Tan[x] + Cos[x], {x, 0, 5}]
g[x]
```

> 1 + x - x^2/2 + x^3/3 + x^4/24 + (2 x^5)/15

```
data2 = Table[Evaluate@{x, Normal@g[x]}, {x, 0, 0.1, 0.01}];

FindFormula[data2, x, TargetFunctions -> {Times, Plus, Sin, Cos, Tan}]
```

> 1. Cos[x] + 1. Tan[x]

Also works fine.

---

```
h[x_] := Normal@Series[Sin[x] Tan[x], {x, 0, 5}]
h[x]
```

> x^2 + x^4/6

```
data3 = Table[Evaluate@{x, Normal@h[x]}, {x, 0, 0.1, 0.01}];

FindFormula[data3, x, TargetFunctions -> {Times, Sin, Cos, Tan, Sec}]
```

> 0.999993 Sin[x] Tan[x]

Almost perfect (doesn't work without `Sec` though).

---

```
k[x_] := Normal@Series[Cos[x]^2 + Sin[x], {x, 0, 4}]
k[x]
```

> 1 + x - x^2 - x^3/6 + x^4/3

```
data4 = Table[Evaluate@{x, Normal@k[x]}, {x, 0, 0.1, 0.01}];

FindFormula[data4, x, TargetFunctions -> {Times, Plus, Sin, Cos}]
```

> Cos[x]^2 + Sin[x]

---

Unfortunately, this fails

```
p[x_] := Normal@Series[Sin[x]^2 + Cos[x], {x, 0, 6}]
p[x]
```

> 1 + x^2/2 - (7 x^4)/24 + (31 x^6)/720

```
data5 = Table[Evaluate@{x, Normal@p[x]}, {x, 0, 0.1, 0.01}];

FindFormula[data5, x, TargetFunctions -> {Times, Plus, Sin, Cos}]
```

> 1 + 0.499998 x^2 - 0.29104 x^4

probably because `Sin[x]^2` is small compared to `Cos[x]`.