# How to find a function from a series with non-numeric coefficients?

Tags: series-expansion

Let us consider a simple example,

```
Series[Exp[a*x], {x, 0, 5}] // Normal
```

Now, I want to revert back to `Exp[a*x]` from it's series expansion.

Is there any such built-in functionality to achieve this?

Thanks to @Szabolcs and @Jenny_mathy for telling me about `FindGeneratingFunction`, which worked for the above example.

**Edit**

But for my actual series, I am not getting any output

```
FindGeneratingFunction[ CoefficientList[a + b x + (c x^2)/2 + 1/6 (b^2 - a c) x^3, x], x]
```

Comment: Look up `FindGeneratingFunction`.

Comment: Possible duplicates: [(38128)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/38128/12) [(133006)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/133006/12)

Answer (score 2):

I think you want something like this as Szabolcs pointed

```
FindGeneratingFunction[
CoefficientList[1 + x + x^2/2 + x^3/6 + x^4/24 + x^5/120, x], x]
```

The function changed, so the new one is

```
FindGeneratingFunction[
CoefficientList[
1 + a x + (a^2 x^2)/2 + (a^3 x^3)/6 + (a^4 x^4)/24 + (a^5 x^5)/120, 
x], x]
```

but it still works

E^(a x)

Comment: But in this case, I am not getting any output. `FindGeneratingFunction[
 CoefficientList[a + b x + (c x^2)/2 + 1/6 (b^2 - a c) x^3, x], x]`

Comment: do you know what the output should be?

Comment: Something exponential, maybe like this $a+c(1-\exp{bx})$ not sure

Comment: I tried this  FindGeneratingFunction[
 CoefficientList[
  a + c + b c x + 1/2 b^2 c x^2 + 1/6 b^3 c x^3 + 1/24 b^4 c x^4 + 
   1/120 b^5 c x^5, x], x] and it works. So the one you are searching must be more complicated

Comment: @MMM I think that it would work better if you fed it with more terms. at least x^4 and x^5...

Comment: No luck with that too...